# release memory of the string char *str = "hello"

Tags: c

Is it required to release the memory allocated to string "str", in the below program ?If so, free(str) works ? In which segment, the memory is allocated to "str" ?

```
int main()
{
    function()
}

function()
{
    char *str="hello";
     --
     --
     return
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char *str= "hello";`

String literal `"Hello"` is stored in `const` region of memory(on most common implementations) and has static storage duration. Any attempt to modify the content would invoke UB i.e `str[0]='c'` would cause segfault on most implementations.

ISO C99 `2.13.4/1` says

> An ordinary string literal has type "array of n const char" and static storage duration.

`'static storage duration' in 3.7.1/1:`

> The storage for these objects shall last for the duration of the program.

---

> Is it required to release the memory allocated to string `"str"`, in the below program ?

Nopes! That would be UB too because the string is not dynamically allocated.

Comment: FYI: UB is "undefined behavior".

Comment: Oh, the allocated memory will be released only after program terminates ? not when the function call returns ? if i use like char str[10]="hello", then it will be stored in stack, and released when function call returns, right ?

Comment: @Gpathy: If you do that, now there are two copies: one temporary modifiable copy on the stack, and the permanent copy somewhere invisible to you that's used to initialize the temporary copy on the stack. Only create strings on the stack when you need to modify them.

Answer (score 3):

String constants are not allocated on the "heap" - where the memory that you need to `free()` is allocated. They are allocated in another special segment, and there's no way to actually "free" this memory - i.e. make it useful for something else in the program. `free(str)` would either lead to a crash (segmentation fault) or if your C library is smart enough it would produce an error notifying you about memory corruption.

You should `free()` only values that you allocated with `malloc()` or return values from functions that are specifically described by the manual as returning `malloc()`ed result that you have to free. Leave the rest alone.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the other answers are pretty complete already, but one thing that hasn't been stressed enough is addressing use of `free`. The *only* pointers you're *ever* allowed to pass to `free` are those obtained via `malloc`, "as if via `malloc`" (some library functions are documented as returning such pointers), or via one of the other `malloc`-related functions (`calloc`, `realloc`, or on POSIX, `posix_memalign`).

It's not a matter of whether you "need to" `free` your string. The much more important thing is that you're not allowed to `free` it. At best (if your C library is very kind to you) it will detect your attempt to `free` a string literal and immediately abort your program. If you're unlucky, you'll silently corrupt memory, and either crash much later when it's hard to track down the root cause, or maybe overwrite important data with corrupt nonsense the next time you click "save" in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you disassemble executable of your code (for ex using gdb) you will be able to see that "hello" is pushed to the stack. Therefore having a scope of lifetime of the function.

Comment: String literals are rarely (never?) put onto the stack. As other posters have mentioned, they're typically in a read-only section of the executable file, and then a pointer to the data in that section is used whenever the literal is.

Comment: oh yes ..you are right..didnt check the code mentioned in the question nicely...thought a buffer was first allocated. :)